# Is there any way to extend the @Configuration class to include the constructor parameter?

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I am writing integration tests for a `Spring Batch` Project, which has the following configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class BatchConfig(
     private JobBuilderFactory factory;
     public BatchConfig(JobBuilderFactory factory) {
           this.factory = factory;
     }
     
     @Bean
     public Step someStep {
       // step implementation
     }
}
```

I created the following base test class

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes=BatchConfig.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class BatchTestBase {
       @Autowired 
       Step someStep
}
```

When I extend this class and try running it, I get the following error

> Parameter 0 of constructor in BatchConfig required a bean of type JobBuilderFactory that could not be found

Is there any way to extend `BatchConfig` to `XML` or add constructor parameters here to access the beans?

Comment: What you _probably_ should do is have an `@TestConfiguration` class that provides a `JobBuilderFactory` bean. Note that `@SpringBootTest` (which says "run the application as it will really be assembled, except that I might mock some of the beans) doesn't typically combine with `@ContextConfiguration`, which is for providing a test-specific configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Create *test context configuration* and use together with a configuration witch need to test in `@ContextConfiguration`

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        BatchTestBase.ContextConfiguration.class,
        BatchConfig.class
})
public class BatchTestBase {

    @Configuration
    static class ContextConfiguration {
        @Bean
        JobBuilderFactory factory() {
            //return fake, mock or stub
        }

    }

    @Autowired
    Step someStep;

    @Test
    public void shouldExecuteStep() {
       //some test
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to inject through set instead of constructor, as it follows :

```
 public setFactory(JobBuilderFactory factory) {
           this.factory = factory;
 }
```